# Xcode 8.2.1. Crashes when creating archive

Tags: swift, xcode8, archive

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
MainQueue: __42-[IDEArchiveManager _revealArchiveAtPath:]_block_invoke
ProductBuildVersion: 8C1002
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-11766.1/IDEProducts/DVTProducts/DVTProducts/DVTProducts/DVTProductVersion.m:45
Details:  version should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string
Object:   <DVTProductVersion: 0x7fe179e7d480>
Method:   -initWithBundleIdentifier:version:buildNumber:name:childProducts:productCategory:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe173c18450>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[DVTProductVersion initWithBundleIdentifier:version:buildNumber:name:childProducts:productCategory:] (in DVTProducts)
  4   +[DVTProductVersion productVersionFromArchive:withError:] (in DVTProducts)
  5   -[DVTArchiveProductSource _productsFromArchives:coordinator:] (in DVTProducts)
  6   __58-[DVTArchiveProductSource updateArchivesDelayedInvocation]_block_invoke (in DVTProducts)
  7   -[DVTDelayedInvocation runBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  8   -[DVTDelayedInvocation invokeIfNeeded] (in DVTFoundation)
  9   -[DVTArchiveProductSource refreshProducts] (in DVTProducts)
 10   +[IDEArchivesViewController revealArchive:] (in IDEProductsUI)
 11   +[IDEArchivesViewController revealArchiveNotification:] (in IDEProductsUI)
 12   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
 13   ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
 14   _CFXRegistrationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 15   ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
 16   -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] (in CoreFoundation)
 17   _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 18   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
 19   -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in DVTFoundation)
 20   __42-[IDEArchiveManager _revealArchiveAtPath:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
 21   ___DVTAsyncPerformBlockOnMainRunLoop_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 22   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
 23   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
 24   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 25   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 26   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 27   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 28   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 29   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 30   -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 31   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 32   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 33   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 34   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
![(version) isEqualToString:@""]
```

Comment: `Details:  version should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string`. Check the version of the app, I think it is empty.

Comment: Check Your Application's Version

Comment: It's not empty. It's set so is the build number.